# evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j}{n\choose i}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Evaluate $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j}{n\choose i}$.

Below is a summary of a solution based off of a problem in the summation chapter of the book Problem Solving Through Problems by Loren Larson.

Multiply both sides of the sum by $\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}}.$

Consider a matching game played with two players A and B and $2n+1$ coins. Player $A$ flips $n+1$ coins and picks $n$ of them so that the number of heads flipped is maximal. Player $B$ flips $n$ coins. The player with the most heads flips wins, with ties going to B.

Then the probability $A$ wins is $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P(\text{ B flips i heads }) \sum_{j=i+1}^n P(\text{ A flips j heads } | \text{ B flips i heads }) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P(\text{ B flips i heads }) \sum_{j=i+1}^n P(\text{ A flips j heads }) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n\choose i}\dfrac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=i+1}^n {n+1\choose j}(\dfrac{1}2)^{n+1}$

Note that the game can be reformulated as follows: players A and B both flip $n$ coins and the one with the most heads flipped wins if there's no tie. If they both flip $n$ heads, then player B wins. If they flip less than n heads and there's a tie, then player A flips the $(n+1)$st coin and wins if it's heads and loses otherwise.

In this case, player B wins exactly two more times than player A (when both players flip n heads). So the probability player A wins is $1-P(\text{B wins}) = 1 - \dfrac{\dfrac{1}2 (2^{2n+1}+2)}{2^{2n+1}} = \dfrac{2^{2n}-1}{2^{2n+1}}.$

Hence the desired answer is $2^{2n}-1.$

> I was wondering if there was a more elementary approach using basic combinatorial identities such as the hockey-stick identity, the Binomial theorem, the identity ${n\choose i} = \dfrac{n}i {n-1\choose i-1},$ etc? Basic rearranging gives that the sum in question equals $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j} \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} {n\choose i}-1.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proof of binomial identity involving double sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268712/proof-of-binomial-identity-involving-double-sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=p+1}^{n+1}
{n+1\choose q} {n\choose p}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n\choose p}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-p} {n+1\choose q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n\choose p}
[v^{n-p}] \frac{1}{1-v} \sum_{q\ge 0} {n+1\choose q} v^q
\\ = [v^n] \frac{1}{1-v}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n\choose p} v^p (1+v)^{n+1}
\\ = -1 +
[v^n] \frac{1}{1-v} (1+v)^{n+1}
 \sum_{p=0}^{n} {n\choose p} v^p
\\ = -1 + [v^n] \frac{1}{1-v} (1+v)^{2n+1}
\\ = -1 + \sum_{q=0}^n {2n+1\choose q}
\\ = -1 + \frac{1}{2} 2^{2n+1}
= -1 + 2^{2n}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you look at [this calculus question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548980/prove-int-01-fxdx-leq-2-int-01-fxdx-int-01-fxdx) if you have time?

Comment: How did you arrive at the second line? Is it some form of the binomial theorem? you are inserting an expansion of $(1+v)^{n-p}$ or something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler proof:

Set
\begin{equation}
L:=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\ \ \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n+1}\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom
{n}{i}.
\end{equation}
(This differs from your sum only in an extra addend, which is obtained for
$i=n$ and $j=n+1$. This extra addend is $1$.)

We claim that $L=2^{2n}$.

Indeed,
\begin{align*}
L=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\ \ \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n+1}}_{=\sum\limits_{0\leq i<j\leq n+1}}
\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom{n}{i}
=\sum\limits_{0\leq i<j\leq n+1}\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom{n}{i}.
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
L  & =\sum\limits_{0\leq i<j\leq n+1}
\underbrace{\dbinom{n+1}{j}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{n+1}{n+1-j}\\
\text{(by the symmetry of}\\\text{binomial
coefficients)}}}\underbrace{\dbinom{n}{i}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{n}{n-i}\\
\text{(by the symmetry of}\\\text{binomial coefficients)}}}\\
& =\sum\limits_{0\leq i<j\leq n+1}\dbinom{n+1}{n+1-j}\dbinom{n}{n-i}\\
& =\sum_{\substack{u,v\in\mathbb{Z};\\0\leq n-u<n+1-v\leq n+1}}
\dbinom{n+1}{v}\dbinom{n}{u}\\
& \qquad\qquad\left(
\begin{array}[c]{c}
\text{here, we have substituted }n-u\text{ and }n+1-v\\
\text{for }i\text{ and }j\text{ in the sum}
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\sum_{\substack{u,v\in\mathbb{Z};\\0\leq v\leq u\leq n}}
\dbinom{n+1}{v}\dbinom{n}{u}\\
& \qquad\qquad\left(
\begin{array}[c]{c}
\text{since the inequalities }0\leq n-u<n+1-v\leq n+1\\
\text{are equivalent to }0\leq v\leq u\leq n
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{0\leq j\leq i\leq n}\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom{n}{i}
\end{align*}
(here, we renamed the indices $u$ and $v$ as $i$ and $j$).

Adding these two equalities together, we find
\begin{align*}
& L+L\\
& =\sum\limits_{0\leq i<j\leq n+1}\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom{n}{i}+\sum
\limits_{0\leq j\leq i\leq n}\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom{n}{i}\\
& =\sum\limits_{\substack{0\leq i\leq n;\\0\leq j\leq n+1}}
\dbinom{n+1}{j}\dbinom{n}{i}\\
& \qquad\qquad\left(
\begin{array}[c]{c}
\text{since the pairs }\left(  i,j\right)  \text{ of integers satisfying}\\
\text{either }0\leq i<j\leq n+1\text{ or }0\leq j\leq i\leq n\text{ are}\\
\text{precisely the ones satisfying }0\leq i\leq n\text{ and }0\leq j\leq n+1
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\underbrace{\left(  \sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\dbinom{n}{i}\right)
}_{\substack{=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{i}=2^{n}\\\text{(by a well-known
property}\\\text{of Pascal's triangle)}}}\underbrace{\left(  \sum_{0\leq j\leq
n+1}\dbinom{n+1}{j}\right)  }_{\substack{=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n+1}\dbinom
{n+1}{j}=2^{n+1}\\\text{(by a well-known property}\\\text{of Pascal's
triangle)}}}\\
& =2^{n}\cdot2^{n+1}=2^{2n+1}.
\end{align*}
Thus, $2L=L+L=2^{2n+1}$. Dividing this equality by $2$, we find $L=2^{2n}$, qed.